# Defining a property name alias

Tags: json, typescript

I have an API from which I cannot change any of the signatures of the objects returned. Unfortunately, the returned values tend to be cryptic as the property names are single characters. It's rather a pain to develop a TypeScript program against these values as the properties aren't terribly descriptive.

Here's the interface for a JSON object I could expect to receive:

```
interface Sample {
  i: string; //Id
  n: string; //Name
  s: State;  //See the enum below
}

enum State {
  Completed = <any>"c",
  Queued = <any>"q",
  Error = <any>"e"
}
```

Some of the values returned can be represented as enums, and I can make this problem a bit easier by taking advantage of the above to capture the value of whatever Sample.s is set to as a single character and now trivially identify what value is what in my code.

However, that leaves me with the interface that has less than ideal property names and no equivalent way to set an "alias" in the same manner.

## Options

I've considered the following with their various pros and cons:

1. Create two interfaces, one that describes the object I'll receive and another with more useful names. Create a function that maps one interface to the other.

**Pros**: I get my trivial names to work against.

**Cons**: I have to maintain two separate objects (one to cast to from the response, one to develop against) for a single JSON response, the former interface and mapping functions being error-prone if the API should ever change.

2. Create a mapping function in the RXJS response to translate the inbound object to an interface with more useful names

**Pros**: I get my trivial names to work against, no second interface to deal with

**Cons**: The sample above is a trivial example. In practice, these would be quite large JSON objects, so the mapping function is going to be non-trivial to write and maintain by hand.

3. Use decorators to provide each property with a JSON value so inbound values can be easily parsed

**Pros**: Trivial property names to develop against, no crazy mappings or second interfaces

**Cons**: Nesting can be problematic, reflection adds quite a lot of cruft to the overall assembly

4. [Constant-named properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#constant-named-properties) almost seem like a decent fit since they'd allow me to do something like:

const StateValue = "s";
interface Sample {
[StateValue]: State;
}

***Cons*** This works fine, except.. the property name in Sample doesn't reflect the "StateValue" name I put there and instead just gives me the JSON values I set the constant to, which entirely misses the point. I'd like to use `Sample.StateValue` and not `Sample.s`.

This can't be an unheard-of problem by now given how popular Typescript is. Is there some way to alias property names that I haven't otherwise found so Typescript will generate the code to use the JSON property names in the output, but otherwise allow me to develop against whatever I otherwise want to call it as I can enums?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're probably looking for adapter pattern.  If any changes happen to 3rd party API it is at least decoupled in such a way that you would ideally only have to change code in your adapter function.  https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-design-patterns-adapter-explained-cbcffbb4b8bc

Comment: That's just another take on option 1 described above. Ideally, I don't want to keep track of two interfaces (one with the original values to cast to and one with the values to develop against).

Comment: I don't see any other choice unless there's a prewritten package that provides syntactic sugar for you to do an easier mapping, similar to C# jsonattribute but for js, which I don't know of off the top of my head